# Cognito SAML server-side login

Tags: go, oauth, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml

I'm actually trying to auth a server (golang) on a Cognito with an external identity provider configured (Azure AD via SAML).

The Cognito / azure AD connection is working well but I can't figure how to authenticate my server.

I'm working with this small piece of code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
    cognito "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"
)

const flowUsernamePassword = "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH"

const AppClientID = "XXXX"
const UserPoolId = "XXXX"

// Login handles login scenario.
func login() {
    conf := &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("eu-west-1")}
    sess, err := session.NewSession(conf)
    CognitoClient := cognito.New(sess)
    username := "xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    password := "XXXX"

    params := map[string]*string{
        "USERNAME": aws.String(username),
        "PASSWORD": aws.String(password),
    }

    authTry := &cognito.AdminInitiateAuthInput{
        AuthFlow:       aws.String(cognitoidentityprovider.AuthFlowTypeAdminUserPasswordAuth),
        AuthParameters: params,
        ClientId:       aws.String(AppClientID),
        UserPoolId:     aws.String(UserPoolId),
    }

    res, err := CognitoClient.AdminInitiateAuth(authTry)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(res.AuthenticationResult)
}

func main() {
    login()
}
```

Where username and password are my Azure AD user.
I can connect on the test hosted UI on Cognito (so the SAML configuration seems to be ok) but when I'm trying to do the same from my golang app, I'm always ending with that error: **NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password.** and I can't figure why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do cannot work. The reason here is - there is no user with such password in your database. The user that is there is a "federated user". Only user's data got synchronized form Azure AD. But the authentication must still happen over Azure AD.

The workflow looks as follow (very simplified):

1. You authenticate with Azure AD
2. Azure AD redirects to Hosted UI
3. Hosted UI retrieves user data from Azure AD (except password, obviously)

You always need to go through Azure AD (or any other federated IDP) if you are using a federated identity provider. You won't be able to directly authenticate with Cognito using the same credentials as you have for your federated IDP.

That's basically the whole point of federated identites.